# Settings variable returning a different value in VB.net!

Tags: vb.net, settings, appsettings

This is a quite strange problem. I have set a setting variable in Application settings with following data:

- **Name**: county
- **Type**: integer
- **Scope**: user
- **Value**: 0

Yet when I reference it with this statement:         `MsgBox(My.MySettings.Default.county)`
It alerts `1`. Despite being the first to  be executed as soon as form loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that the `My.MySettings` bit is a typo.

Often when someone sees a different value than they expect when reading from `My.Settings`, it seems to be that they are reading the `Default` rather than the actual value.
I'd suggest trying to use just `MsgBox(My.MySettings.county)` and see if that returns what you want.

Otherwise, try to delete the `bin` and `object` directories of the project and try to re-compile and re-run and see if it might be something that had gotten "stuck" somewhere.

Comment: This time I used `My.Settings.county` deleting both `obj` and `bin` and still the value comes to `1`.

Comment: @shubham: Well if you're reading without the `Default` it should definitely be reading from the .config file. What value is in the .config file in the `bin\debug` (or `bin\release` etc depending on what you're running) directory?

Comment: Well I just now deleted the old config files and recompiled and it worked. Thanks!